# Is it permissible for a husband and wife to bathe together?

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife

Is it permissible in Islam for a husband and wife to bathe together?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: There are even ahadith on the Prophet pbuh bathing with some of his wives.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

They are allowed to see every part of each other as they are married. Bathing or showering together is fine as is having relations there.